# How to plot a CVS file with python? My plot comes up blank

Tags: python

I have the code below that seems to run without issues until I try to plot it. A blank plot will show when asked to plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('/home/oem/Documents/620157.csv', delimiter=',',   skip_header=01, skip_footer=01, names=['x', 'y'])

plt.plot(data,'o-')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but I believe you need to do something like this:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('/home/oem/Documents/620157.csv', 
                     delimiter=',',   
                     skip_header=1, 
                     skip_footer=1)
name, x, y, a, b = zip(*data)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
```

As per your comment, the data is currently an array containing tuples of the station name and the x and y data.  Using `zip` with the `*` symbol assigns them back to individual variables which can then be used for plotting.

Comment: So, I am actually not sure - I have five columns on this file - its a weather data file, one column with station names and the other columns with data which all seem to be the same.  I know this is a silly question but do I assign a variable to each column?

Comment: See edit.  I'm not sure of the order of your columns, so I can't be more precise without seeing the header of the csv file.

Comment: Hi, the data looks like this:

Comment: *every COOP would indicate the start of a new row - COOP:194580 62.5 42.4293 -71.4425 201501 113 32 5      434
COOP:194580 62.5 42.4293 -71.4425 201502 92 41 9 355 
COOP:194580 62.5 42.4293 -71.4425 201503 65 30 2 213

Comment: however, the only columns I want to plot are E and F, for example.

Comment: String IO seems to help in choosing/skipping columns, your help was very good as well, thank you